# Text-Overflow: Ellipsis Not Working with Text-Align: Center in Chrome/Safari?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, ellipsis, text-align

Why would `text-overflow: ellipsis` horizontally align differently in Firefox than in Chrome and Safari?

Here are some images that show what I am referring to:

**How I would like it to display (Firefox):**

`text-overflow: ellipsis` with `text-align: center` applied in Firefox:

[image]

**How I do not want it to display (Chrome/Safari):**

`text-overflow: ellipsis` with `text-align: center` applied in Chrome/Safari:

[image]

It seems that in Chrome and Safari, the text-align is being applied to the text, disregarding the ellipsis; whereas in Firefox, it wraps around all of the text, including the ellipsis.

Here is what I have written in CSS for the div element shown above:

```
.textblock {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```